# Write response from JSON Array to Google Chart and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, google-visualization

I have a google chart code like below

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
 google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

 // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

 // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
 // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.
function drawChart() {
 // Create the data table.
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn('string', 'Type');    
     data.addColumn('number', 'Total');
     data.addRows([
      ['Damage', 3],
      ['Lost', 1]
    ]);
 // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new 
  google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
  }
  </script>
```

I want to insert with json api array like below

```
    "status": 200,
    "message": "OK",
    "data": [
     {
       "_id": {
       "report_type": "robbery"
        },
        "report_type": "robbery",
        "Counts": 11
      },
      {
         "_id": {
         "report_type": "property_damage"
          },
         "report_type": "property_damage",
          "Counts": 39
     },
     {
        "_id": {
        "report_type": null
         },
        "report_type": null,
        "Counts": 2
     }
    ]
```

I want to change `type` and `total` in the google chart above with `report_type` and `Counts` value in api.

I have tried write code below, but the results is not coming

```
   function drawChart() {
     $.ajax({
     url: "api-url",
     type: "GET",
     success: function (data) {
       var arrReport = [['Type', 'Total']];

      $.each(data, function (index, value) {
      arrReport.push([value.data.report_type, value.data.Counts]);
     });

     var options = {
    'width':400,
    'height':300
     };

     var figures = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrReport)

     var chart = new 
     google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

     chart.draw(figures, google.visualization.PieChart(options));
    }
   });
  }
```

Do you know where's the error from my code ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the following is the json you are receiving...

```
"status": 200,
"message": "OK",
"data": [
 {
   "_id": {
   "report_type": "robbery"
    },
    "report_type": "robbery",
    "Counts": 11
  },
  {
     "_id": {
     "report_type": "property_damage"
      },
     "report_type": "property_damage",
      "Counts": 39
 },
 {
    "_id": {
    "report_type": null
     },
    "report_type": null,
    "Counts": 2
 }
]
```

in the following `data` argument,
then you should be looping on --> `data.data`
and accessing the values as --> `value.report_type` & `value.Counts`

```
  var arrReport = [['Type', 'Total']];

  $.each(data.data, function (index, value) {
    arrReport.push([value.report_type, value.Counts]);
  });
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
    width: 400,
    height: 300
  };
  var arrReport = [['Type', 'Total']];
  var figures;

  // will fail here on SO
  $.ajax({
    url: 'api-url',
    type: 'GET'
  }).done(function (data) {

    drawChart(data);

  }).fail(function () {
    // draw with hard-coded data, for example purposes
    var data = {
      "status": 200,
      "message": "OK",
      "data": [
       {
         "_id": {
         "report_type": "robbery"
          },
          "report_type": "robbery",
          "Counts": 11
        },
        {
           "_id": {
           "report_type": "property_damage"
            },
           "report_type": "property_damage",
            "Counts": 39
       },
       {
          "_id": {
          "report_type": null
           },
          "report_type": null,
          "Counts": 2
       }
      ]
    };

    drawChart(data);

  });

  function drawChart(data) {
    $.each(data.data, function (index, value) {
      arrReport.push([value.report_type, value.Counts]);
    });
    figures = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrReport);
    chart.draw(figures, options);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

NOTES:

1) you should be using the newer library `loader.js`

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

instead of `jsapi`, according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement, see above snippet.

2) `google.visualization.PieChart` -- should be removed here --> `chart.draw(figures, options);`

Comment: Hi @WhiteHat, I have tried your code, and modified and using half of it, and it works.

Comment: Hope you can help my another question

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing with API Url Like,

```
$.ajax({
       url: "api-url",
       type: "GET",
       success: function (data) {
});
```

Assumed the API Url in a variable so it should be-

```
$.ajax({
           url: api-url,
           type: "GET",
           success: function (data) {
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I have changed url into variable and it's still not working